# How to insert the foreign key in the Referance table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

when I fill up the web service data then I want to insert foreign key??

first i create a 2 table

**tblpersonal**:

```
studid int  (primary key identity increment)
fname varchar(50)
mname varchar(50)
lname varchar(50)
```

tblcontact

```
contactid int  (primary key identity increment)
emailid  varchar(50)
password  varchar(50)
contactno  varchar(50)
hobby  varchar(50)
address varchar(50)
countrycodenum varchar(50)
studid (foreign key tblpersonal)
```

issue is when fillup the webservice then not insert the foreign key that is issue see below image

[image]

WebService1.asmx.cs

```
namespace WebServiceDemo
{

    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString);
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string InsertData(string fname, string mname, string lname, string emailid, string password, string contactno, string hobby, string address, string countrycodenum)
        {
            cn.Open();

            var dataObject = new { fname , mname , lname , emailid , password , contactno , hobby , address , countrycodenum };

            string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataObject);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertsp_singlesp", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", mname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailid", emailid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactno", contactno);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hobby", hobby);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countrycodenum", countrycodenum);

            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (i > 0)
            {              
                Console.WriteLine("Insert Successfully");
            }
            else
            {              
                Console.WriteLine("Not Insert Successfully");
            }
            cn.Close();
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

store procedure : insertsp_singlesp

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertsp_singlesp] 
    @fname varchar(50),
    @mname varchar(50),
    @lname varchar(50),
    @emailid varchar(50),
    @password varchar(50),
    @contactno varchar(50),
    @hobby varchar(50),
    @address varchar(50),
    @countrycodenum varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
   insert into tblpersonal(fname, mname, lname)values(@fname,@mname,@lname);
   insert into tblcontact(emailid, password,contactno,hobby,address,countrycodenum)values(@emailid,@password,@contactno,@hobby,@address,@countrycodenum);
END
```

**Below image is give the foreign key in another table**:

[image]

please help?

Comment: You should properly explain your issue. Please try to edit the explanation.

Comment: question is very simple tblpersonal(studid-1011) insert in another table tblcontact(studid is a foreign key - here I want to insert 1011)

Comment: @Nish What didn't you understand tell me?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the StoredProcedure to capture the last IDENTITY value inserted in the current connection, then use this value to set your FK value

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertsp_singlesp] 
    @fname varchar(50),
    @mname varchar(50),
    @lname varchar(50),
    @emailid varchar(50),
    @password varchar(50),
    @contactno varchar(50),
    @hobby varchar(50),
    @address varchar(50),
    @countrycodenum varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
   insert into tblpersonal(fname, mname, lname)values(@fname,@mname,@lname);
   declare @studid int
   SELECT @studid = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
   insert into tblcontact(
               emailid, password,contactno,hobby,
               address,countrycodenum,studid)
         values(
                @emailid,@password,@contactno,@hobby,
                @address,@countrycodenum,@studid);
END
```

Comment: Glad to be helpful, and looking at your code I wish also to suggest to remove the creation of parameters with AddWithValue. It is dangerous and not performant with Sql Server

Answer (score 1):

You simply aren't providing the PK of your first table when you insert into the second table. There is no 'magic' that will allow a SQL system to say 'yep - that is the one he means'.

You don't say what system you are using but it looks to me like SQL Server so I'll continue using that. You need to use the SCOPE_IDENTITY() function to get the last identity generated, after your first insert, and then use it in the second:

```
BEGIN
   declare @ssi int;
   insert into tblpersonal(fname, mname, lname)values(@fname,@mname,@lname);
   -- get the identity just created
   select @ssi = scope_identity();
   -- use it in the insert
   insert into tblcontact (emailid, password, contactno, 
                          hobby, address, countrycodenum, studid)
        values (@emailid, @password, @contactno,
                @hobby, @address, @countrycodenum, @ssi);
END
```